# What does it mean if I don't provide an InitialCatalog in a OLEDB connection string?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, oledb, connection-string

I have a connection string (to an SQLServer 2005 database) which specifies a server, username and password, but does not specify an InitialCatalog.  When I try and open connection it works, and I can list the tables, which lists a lot of tables, but not the table from the database I am interested in.

What is it I am connected to when no InitialCatalog is specified.  Why is it valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not specify the database, the default, as configured for the user will be used.

You can issue a "Use DatabaseName" statement to switch databases.

You can view the default database by looking at the properties of the user account.  By default I believe it is the "master" database.

Answer (score 1):

Each user has a default database. If you don't specify the initial catalog, you will connect to that database.